# can't install opencv with cocoapods, Could not resolve host: hivelocity.dl.sourceforge.net

Tags: ios, swift, opencv

```
Last login: Tue Jun 23 18:31:21 on ttys000
Peters-MacBook-Pro:~ WaTT$ cd Downloads/Starter/
Peters-MacBook-Pro:Starter WaTT$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Installing OpenCV (2.4.10)

[!] Error installing OpenCV
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/md/mjx0zhrx3ks3ybfhj7dxjksh0000gn/T/d20150623-3952-1mkdgjs/file.zip http://hivelocity.dl.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-ios/2.4.10/opencv2.framework.zip --create-dirs

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: hivelocity.dl.sourceforge.net
```

First, I have installed cocoapods correctly, because I can install AFNetworking. 
Second, Although I am in China, I have tried VPN. 
Third, In my Podfile, I just write pod 'OpenCV'

I know I can use OpenCV without cocoapods, but I still want to solve this problem.

Comment: Is a bad question? I have not clue yet.

Answer (score 9):

OpenCV is hosted by Sourceforge, which seems to be unreliable for these kind of hard-coded links.

As an alternative, here are a couple of self-hosted podspecs for 2.4.9 and 2.4.10 that you should be able to use:

https://github.com/Zi0P4tch0/Specs/tree/master/Specs/OpenCV

Your podfile should look something like this:

```
source 'https://github.com/Zi0P4tch0/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'OpenCV', '2.4.9-zp'
```

These were set up to support my [OpenCVSwiftStitch](https://github.com/foundry/OpenCVSwiftStitch) demo project, as I couldn't get the official podspec paths to work.

In my experience 2.4.10 is [broken anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28331397/cocoapods-opencv-2-4-10-linker-error/28820510), so 2.4.9 is the preferred option.

3.0.0 also seems to be fine as manual download. No podspec, but the framework available from (http://openCV.org) just worked for me when I dragged it into the SwiftStitch project.

Comment: I tried the whole night, but your magical answer worked for me... thanks a lot for saving further time

Answer (score 5):

A temporary work-around is to edit the local pod spec with

```
pod spec edit opencv
```

and replace the no longer valid download URL with

```
http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-ios/2.4.10/opencv2.framework.zip
```

and wait until the pod gets fixed. Ideally - open an issue for it.

Comment: the --show-all option may come in handy so that you edit the podspec for the version you are trying to install.